# AWS EKS and cross account source security group rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

cross account source SG reference doesn't work for EKS. With SG rule below I'm able just reach only EKS node, but not any PODs in cluster.
With specifying same rule with source IP of EC2, or source SG in the same account, it works as expeted, but apparently there is some sort of issue, or limitations in cross account source SG solution.
I assume, it has something to do with Network Interfaces for EKS, where AWS uses primary private IP(node IP) and secondary private IPs for PODs....maybe?
SG for pod is not solution for me right now (https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/networking/sgpp/)

*prerequisites:*
One VPC shared cross accounts
EC2 with security group SG-EC2-ACCOUNT1 located in Account1
EKS cluster(kubernetes version 1.25) with security group SG-EKS-ACCOUNT2 in Account2

*scenario:*
I want to gain access from EC2 in Account1 into EKS cluster in Account2. Because EC2(or another AWS resources like RDS, EKS) obtains IP dynamically, best practice is to add new SG rule in SG-EKS-ACCOUNT2 with source SG of EC2 instead of its IP.

```
SG rule in SG-EKS-ACCOUNT2:
Security group rule ID Type  Protocol Port range Source             Description
sgr-xxxxxxxxxxxx       HTTPS TCP      443  <Account1_ID>/SG-EC2-ACCOUNT1 cross account access
```

Comment: Not sure this applies to your environment, but you can specify a security group when you configure custom networking for the VPC CNI. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html#custom-networking-configure-kubernetes.